# Binding CocoaPods library using Objective Sharpie

Tags: c#, objective-c, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have been trying to bind a cocoaPods library written in objective-c using the Objective sharpie tool. I also have the .framework files.

First i tried to import the .Framework files under the native references on visual studio (IOS Project) then connected my VS to a MacOS with the needed SDK installed and built the app. The app built but did nothing with the native references. So i gave objective sharpie a shot. This is what i am doing:

After i installed cocoapods and objective sharpie I created a single page app in XCode. Navigated to the project directory in the Terminal, and executed the command:

```
sharpie pod init ios BiometridAuth
```

and got this result:

```
** Setting up CocoaPods master repo...
(this may take a while the first time)
** Searching for requested CocoaPods...
error: Could not find CocoaPod: BiometridAuth
hint: try grepping 'pod list' ?
```

So objective sharpie doesnt find the pod... but it exists because when i put it in the pod file and install it via cocoapods it installs correctly. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Hi , you create  a single page app in XCode ?  You can refer to this document [Creating a binding for a CocoaPod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/cocoapod#creating-a-binding-for-a-cocoapod) for reference .

Comment: i did everything they say in that document... still no luck. Have you done this before ?

Comment: Yeah , used before . Today the network of my computer is not stable . When using `sharpie pod init xxx` it stop at `Searching ...` all the time . Later , when network is well will retry it.

Comment: This hangs at this 'searching' step as well for me as of today

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by the Xamarin team（[comment-1](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/8238#issuecomment-606239665), [comment-2](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/8238#issuecomment-606666460)）, the `sharpie pod` command is deprecated.

So, in order to generate `ApiDefinitions.cs` and `StructuresAndEnums.cs` from pod, you can use the following `sharpie bind`.

```sh
sharpie bind \
      -o BiometridAuth \
      -sdk iphoneos13.2 \
      -scope . \
      Pods/BiometridAuth/BiometridAuth.framework/Headers/*
```

Also, you can check the parameters for `-sdk` argument with `sharpie xcode --sdks`.

```sh
sharpie xcode --sdks

sdk: appletvos13.4    arch: arm64
sdk: appletvos13.2    arch: arm64
sdk: iphoneos13.6     arch: arm64   armv7
sdk: iphoneos13.5     arch: arm64   armv7
sdk: iphoneos13.4     arch: arm64   armv7
sdk: iphoneos13.2     arch: arm64   armv7
sdk: macosx10.15      arch: x86_64  i386
sdk: watchos6.2       arch: armv7k
sdk: watchos6.1       arch: armv7k
```